# ubuntu 18.04: Delay screen from going black after manually selecting lock

Tags: 18.04, lock-screen, lock

I was wondering if there was any way of **delaying** the screen from going black after **manually selecting lock** from the menu pane.  If possible I'd like to set the lock screen itself to go black after 20 minutes and not immediately.

Comment: Did you mean to write _delay_ the screen from going black after manually locking?

Comment: Yes that sounds right